# Why are my JSON property names being folded to lower case?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a Cloud Endpoint app, where my REST JSON looks like this

```
{
   "FIRST_NAME": "robert"
}
```

and is mapped to my JDO object, thus

```
private String FIRST_NAME
```

The problem I have is that this fails, the GCE code fails to recognise `FIRST_NAME`. I looked at the API Explorer, and the generated endpoint expects `first_NAME`.

When I create a test client to generate JSON with `first_NAME` it works fine.

Sadly however, the client that will generate the JSON in production is outside of my control, so I can't change the fact that it is sending FIRST_NAME in all capitals.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the GCE in your control? Could you change it so that it accepts FIRST_NAME instead of first_NAME? (both seem odd to me by the way...)

Comment: I control GCE, but not the client. I couldn't see anywhere I can influence the generation process, so I gave up. I've written a simple servlet to deal with the client POSTS directly (bypassing GCE). I agree it looks odd. Not my client so not much I can do about it.

Comment: Is this `POST` or `GET`? Are you receiving or returning said object? Could you update with the cloud endpoints method and a screenshot of the explorer where it says it expects `first_NAME`?